# Android leaked activity

Tags: php, android, mysqli

I am using MySQL database to get students info. I followed a tutorial and Android leaked window shows up. Here is the code for calling the async task and get the data from the database.

```
class getallstudents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SecondActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest("http://127.0.0.1/testphp/get_all_students.php", "GET", params);  
            try {
                String st_id = json.getString(Tag_st_id);
                String st_name = json.getString(Tag_st_name);
                String st_phone = json.getString(Tag_st_phone);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

         protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        tv2.setText(Tag_st_id);
                        TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                        tv3.setText(Tag_st_name);
                        TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                        tv4.setText(Tag_st_phone);
                        }
                });

            }
}
}
```

Comment: `onPostExecute` runs already on the UI Thread. There is no reason to use `runOnUiThread`

Comment: can you post your LOGCAT output when leak happens?

Comment: i removed the runOnUiThread and it crashed

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, so am suggesting it is closed as not containing sufficient info to diagnose.